# How to encapsulate in clojure?

Tags: clojure, wrapper, encapsulation

I have some clojure code that looks like this:

```
(defn rect [x y w h]
  {:x x, :y y, :w w, :h h})

(def left :x)
(def top :y)
(def width :w)
(def height :h)

(defn right [r]
  (+ (left r) (width r)))

(defn bottom [r]
  (+ (top r) (height r)))
```

Now the following code seems a bit uncommon:

```
(def left :x)
```

However I don't know any other way to get encapsulation.

Suppose, I later want to represent my rect a different way.
Then relying on (:x rect) is not a good idea, because :x only works on hashmap's and records, so then I would be leaking implementation details in the api, which at least in OO languages is considered bad practice.

Now, if I decide to implement my rect in java instead, it gets even worse, because then I would have to write wrappers like:

```
(defn left [rect] (.getLeft rect))
```

to make sure the interface doesn't change.

How does clojure get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use protocols.

First a Clojure record:

```
(defprotocol Rectangular
  (left [this])
  (right [this]))

(defrecord Rect [x y w h]
  Rectangular
  (left [this] x)
  (right [this] (+ x w)))

(def my-rect (Rect. 1 2 3 4))
(right my-rect) ;=> 4
```

Now a Java object:

```
(import java.awt.Rectangle)

(extend-type Rectangle
  Rectangular
  (left [this] (int (.getX this)))
  (right [this] (int (+ (.getX this) (.getWidth this)))))

(def my-other-rect (Rectangle. 1 2 3 4))
(right my-other-rect) ;=> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Clojure has [protocols and types](http://clojure.org/datatypes). You identify an abstraction with a protocol (like Java interfaces) and you create implementations for those abstractions. There also are [multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods) which give you more freedom over how method dispatch occurs.

However, structuring your data in the way you have in your example is very common. Take a look at the [Leiningen project file](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/project.clj) and the contents of [Ring requests and responses](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Concepts). Even if you decided to completely change how you lookup the values of x and y, you can simply create a type that operates on the same abstraction as a map. In this case, that's the [ILookup protocol](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/ILookup.java).